# Uploading files to server without Zend_Form_Element_File

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework but i want to upload files to my server with pure
HTML & PHP!(No Zend_Form).
the big question is, where should i Upload?(url?) and how can i download file from server(how to link to files)?
Zend Framework rewrites  URLs and i can not link directly to files.

Answer (score 0):

All files are uploaded in "tmp" folder which you can change in php.ini if you like,after request completes php delete the uploaded file from tmp folder automatically so you need to move this file to any location you want . Zend do not rewrite url , to access file directly you need to move files inside public folder , and if you are not using Zend_Form then use Zend_file directly.

Comment: can you show me a little code?i used  [this](http://www.developer.com/lang/php/article.php/3844031/Managing-File-Uploads-with-the-Zend-Framework.htm) but when i call setDestenation("path") , i don't know where should i set!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PHP manual, it will help you a lot:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php